# Can't parse JSON because of trailing whitespaces in JSON String

Tags: node.js, json, parsing

I'm currently working on a web scraper and I'm getting the JSON from `<script type="application/ld+json>` on a particular web page. I get it as a string using Cheerio and pass it on a JSON parser (npm package). But I keep on getting a syntax error and this happens if the value has a trailing white space.

I tried the reviver by trimming each value but it still doesn't work.

This is a snippet of my JSON string where I get a Syntax Error:

```
{"...821", "description":"                                                  \r\n
                                ","@type":"Organization",...}
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
ErrorEXError [JSONError]: Unexpected token       in JSON at position 1432 while parsing near '...821","description":"                                                \r\n                                             ","...'
```

How can I trim the `description` value without string manipulation?

Comment: `without string manipulation?` Huh? You'll *have* to manipulate the string *somehow* in order to change it to make it parseable, what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A properly formatted JSON string must not contain any literal newline characters - it can only contain *representations* of newline characters, such as with `\r\n`. Replace all literal newlines with `\n`, and you should be able to parse it properly:

```js
const jsonStr = `{"description":"                                                  \r\n
                                ","@type":"Organization"}`;
const jsonStrWithoutNewlines = jsonStr.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '\\n');
const obj = JSON.parse(jsonStrWithoutNewlines);
console.log(obj);
```

Literal tab characters aren't permitted either - if that's an issue, replace them with `\t`:

```js
const jsonStr = `{"description":"                                                  \r\n
                                ","@type":"Organization   "}`;
const jsonStrWithoutNewlines = jsonStr
  .replace(/[\n\r]+/g, '\\n')
  .replace(/\t/g, '\\t');
const obj = JSON.parse(jsonStrWithoutNewlines);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Yet another example how JSON is overused for “human editable” configuration files..